# Skip validation for certain fields in Struts2

Tags: java, validation, struts2

For example, there is an action class as follows.

```
@Namespace("/admin_side")
@ResultPath("/WEB-INF/content")
@InterceptorRefs({@InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params={"validation.excludeMethods", "load"})})
public final class TestAction extends ActionSupport implements Serializable, ValidationAware, ModelDriven<Transporter>
{
    @Autowired
    private final transient TransporterService transporterService=null;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Boolean deleteOneRow=false; //Getter and setter.
    private Transporter entity=new Transporter(); //Getter and setter.
    private List<Transporter>transporters=new ArrayList<Transporter>();
    private String message; //Getter and setter.
    private List<Long>chk; //Getter and setter.

    @Action(value = "Transporter", results = {@Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, location="Transporter.jsp"), @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Transporter.jsp")})
    public String load() throws Exception
    {
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Validations(
            requiredStrings={
                @RequiredStringValidator(fieldName="transporterName", type= ValidatorType.FIELD, key = "transporter.name.required"),
                @RequiredStringValidator(fieldName="transporterWebsite", type= ValidatorType.FIELD, key = "transporter.website.required")},
            stringLengthFields={
                @StringLengthFieldValidator(fieldName="transporterName", type= ValidatorType.FIELD, minLength="2", maxLength="45", key="transporter.name.length", messageParams={"2", "45"}),
                @StringLengthFieldValidator(fieldName="transporterWebsite", type= ValidatorType.FIELD, minLength="10", maxLength="1000", key="transporter.website.length", messageParams={"10", "1000"})})
    @Action(value = "addTransporter",
        results = {@Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type="redirectAction", location="Transporter.jsp", params={"namespace", "/admin_side", "actionName", "Transporter", "message", "${message}"}),
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Transporter.jsp")},
        interceptorRefs={@InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params={"params.acceptParamNames", "transporterName, transporterWebsite", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"})})
    public String insert()
    {
        if(entity.getTransporterId()==null)
        {
            transporterService.insert(entity.getTransporterName(), entity.getTransporterWebsite());
            setMessage(getText("insert.success"));
        }
        else
        {
            setMessage(transporterService.update(entity)?getText("update.success", new String[]{String.valueOf(entity.getTransporterId())}) :getText("update.failed", new String[]{String.valueOf(entity.getTransporterId())}));
        }
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Validations(requiredFields={@RequiredFieldValidator(fieldName="transporterId", type= ValidatorType.FIELD, key = "delete.id.missing")})
    @Action(value = "editTransporter",
            results = {
                @Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, location="Transporter.jsp"),
                @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Transporter.jsp")},
            interceptorRefs={
                @InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params={"params.acceptParamNames", "transporterId, transporterName, transporterWebsite", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"}),
                @InterceptorRef(value="conversionError")})
    public String edit()
    {
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Action(value = "deleteTransporter",
            results = {
                @Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type="redirectAction", location="Transporter.action", params={"message", "${message}"}),
                @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Transporter.jsp")},
            interceptorRefs={
                @InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params={"params.acceptParamNames", "transporterId, deleteOneRow", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"}),
                @InterceptorRef(value="conversionError")})
    public String deleteTransporter()
    {
        if(transporterService.delete(entity.getTransporterId()))
        {
            //Pagination has not not yet been implemented. Hence, it is static.
            transporters=transporterService.getList(0, 20); 
            setMessage(getText("delete.success", new String[]{String.valueOf(entity.getTransporterId())}));
        }
        else
        {
            setMessage(getText("delete.failed", new String[]{String.valueOf(entity.getTransporterId())}));
        }
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Action(value = "deleteTransporters",
            results = {
                @Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type="redirectAction", location="Transporter.jsp", params={"namespace", "/admin_side", "actionName", "Transporter", "message", "${message}"}),
                @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Transporter.jsp")},
            interceptorRefs={
                @InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params={"params.acceptParamNames", "chk", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"}),
                @InterceptorRef(value="conversionError")})
    public String deleteTransporters()
    {
        setMessage(transporterService.delete(chk)?getText("delete.multiple.success", new String[]{String.valueOf(chk.size())}) :getText("delete.multiple.failed"));
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public Transporter getModel() {
        return entity;
    }

    public List<Transporter> getTransporters()
    {
        if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(transporters))
        {
            //Pagination has not not yet been implemented. Hence, it is static.
            transporters=transporterService.getList(0, 20);
        }
        return transporters;
    }

    public void setTransporters(List<Transporter> transporters) {
        this.transporters = transporters;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(){}
}
```

**The JSP page:**

```xml
<s:form namespace="/admin_side" action="Transporter" id="dataForm" name="dataForm" cssClass="search_form general_form">
    <s:if test="hasFieldErrors()">
        <s:fielderror fieldName="transporterId"/>
        <s:fielderror fieldName="chk"/>
    </s:if>

    <s:property value="message"/>
    <s:hidden id="transporterId" name="transporterId"/>
    <s:hidden id="deleteOneRow" name="deleteOneRow"/>

   <s:textfield id="transporterName" name="transporterName"/><s:fielderror fieldName="transporterName"/>
   <s:textfield id="transporterWebsite" name="transporterWebsite"/><s:fielderror fieldName="transporterWebsite"/>
   <s:submit id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" action="addTransporter"/>

   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="even">
                <th style="width: 96px;">Check</th>
                <th style="width: 96px;">Id</th>
                <th style="width: 96px;">Transporter</th>
                <th style="width: 96px;">Website</th>
                <th style="width: 96px;">Actions</th>
            </tr>
            <s:iterator value="transporters" status="loopStatus">
                <tr class="<s:if test="#loopStatus.odd == true ">first</s:if> <s:else>second</s:else>">
                    <td><s:checkbox name="chk" fieldValue="%{transporterId}" value="false"/></td>
                    <td><s:property value="transporterId" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="transporterName" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="<s:property value="transporterWebsite" />">Visit</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class='actions'>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <s:url id="editURL" action="editTransporter" escapeAmp="false">
                                        <s:param name="transporterId" value="%{transporterId}"/>
                                        <s:param name="transporterName" value="%{transporterName}"/>
                                        <s:param name="transporterWebsite" value="%{transporterWebsite}"/>
                                    </s:url>
                                    <s:a href="%{editURL}" cssClass="action2"/>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <s:url id="deleteURL" action="deleteTransporter" escapeAmp="false">
                                        <s:param name="transporterId" value="%{transporterId}"/>
                                        <s:param name="deleteOneRow" value="%{deleteOneRow}"/>
                                    </s:url>
                                    <s:a href="%{deleteURL}" onclick="return deleteOne(%{transporterId});" cssClass="action4"/>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<s:submit name="btnDelete" id="btnDelete" action="deleteTransporters" onclick="return getCheckedRows();" />
```

The `insert()` method accepts two parameters, `transporterName` and `transporterWebsite` and the `edit()` method accepts only one parameter `transporterId` which is supplied as a query-string, when a link is clicked.

The `insert()` method is mapped by an action of `<s:submit>` whereas the `edit()` method is mapped by an action of `<s:url>` whose `id` is given to the `href` attribute of `<s:a>`.

When the edit link, `<s:a>` is clicked, both the text fields `transporterName` and `transporterWebsite` are unnecessarily validated which must not happen while editing i.e validation to these text fields should be skipped/disabled, when the edit link is clicked.

Only `transporterId` which is accepted by the `edit()` method should be validated. No other fields should be validated, when the edit link is clicked.

The annotation `@SkipValidation` would not work, in this case.

How to do this?

Comment: I have edited the post to include the complete code.

Comment: How did you check that other fields have been validated?

Comment: The validation criteria is slightly changed after the edit (I have implemented `ModelDriven<Transporter>`). For example, in this example, it prevents a new row from being created  validating `transporterId` unnecessarily which is only required while editing a row in `<table>` and not while creating a new row. Similarly, while deleting multiple rows (the last line in the JSP code, `<s:submit>`), both the text fields namely `transporterName` and `transporterWebsite` and also `transporterId` are validated preventing the selected rows from being deleted which shouldn't happen anymore.

Comment: `transporterName`, `transporterWebsite` and `transporterId` are also validated while deleting a single row. Regarding Spring MVC this doesn't happen. If a parameter is eliminated from the accept list of parameters then, validation to that field is also eliminated. That field is not validated then onward. The same thing should be applicable to Struts but this doesn't seem to be the case of Struts.

Comment: I see you are using a client-side validation along with server-side, but can't get which one is not working?

Comment: The client-side validation is not concerned here (I'm going to remove `validate="true"` from the `<s:form>` tag). The server-side validation also works fine but **regarding different actions**, some fields are **unnecessary to be validated**. If A action is triggered then X field need not be validated. If B action is triggered then, Y field should be skipped from being validated as specified in the previous comments.

Comment: A tiny example : I have two text fields with name attributes `x` and `y` and two buttons `a` and `b`. How can we say, when the button `a` pressed then only the text field `x` is validated and when the button `b` is pressed then only the text field `y` is validated? Not both fields should be validated, when either of the buttons is pressed (regarding server-side validation).

Comment: Could you print out errors in the `validate` method for both cases?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get properly. The `validate()` method is empty. I haven't yet used it but the corresponding error messages are displayed on the form.

Comment: In the validate method you can use `ActionSupport::getFieldErrors()` and print out them on console.

Comment: Yes the `Map` displays the validation error messages in the `validate()` method exactly the same as they appear on the form. [This](http://pastebin.com/MVDhyYV0) is the loop I have tried in the `validate()` method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44108/discussion-between-roman-c-and-tiny)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because I was missing `validateAnnotatedMethodOnly` at the class level validation interceptor I defined.

It worked when I modified the class definition to something like the following.

```
@Namespace("/admin_side")
@ResultPath("/WEB-INF/content")
@InterceptorRefs({@InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params={"validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true", "validation.excludeMethods", "load"})})
public final class TestAction  extends ActionSupport implements Serializable, ValidationAware, ModelDriven<Transporter>
{
    //...
}
```

I included `validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly` at method levels but forgot to include it at the class level.

<sub>It would have also been appropriate to just annotate the `load()` method in the action class with `@SkipValidation` and eliminate the class level `@InterceptorRefs` annotation in its entirely.</sub>

---

From the [documentation](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/validation-annotation.html):

> When multiple methods are used to map different actions on the same
>   class, and one of them is annotated with `@Validations`, those
>   validators will be triggered for all the actions, unless they are
>   annotated with `@SkipValidation` or `validateAnnotatedMethodOnly` is set
>   to true in the `validation` interceptor, like:
>
> ```
> <interceptor-ref name="validation">
>     <param name="validateAnnotatedMethodOnly">true</param>
>     <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
> </interceptor-ref>
> ```

Comment: Annotations on class are applied to all actions in the class by convention.